# How are IP addresses assigned for two routers in the same network?

Tags: networking, router

Let’s say I have a home network with a router which goes to the main router which in turn goes to Internet

In this case how is my network seen from the main router in terms of IP addressing?

If the main router has internal IP of 192.168.0.1 (meaning, it’s sharing it’s network with bunch of other computers connected to LAN ports)

In case my other router is connected to the LAN port of the main, will the second router be on the 192.168.0.2 e.g. ? or will it be on a different subnet, let’s say 192.168.1.1 ?

Comment: It depends entirely on how you configured it. It's usually best to drop any secondary router into bridge mode, taking it effectively out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

> In case my other router is connected to the LAN port of the main, will the second router be on the 192.168.0.2 e.g. ? or will it be on a different subnet, let’s say 192.168.1.1 ?

**Both.** As a device that connects networks, a router will almost always have IP addresses from *each* of the networks that it's connected to. So on the "WAN" interface it will have an 192.168.0.x address (probably received via DHCP, like hosts get theirs) while on the "LAN" interface it will have an 192.168.1.x address.

Note that the first router is *unaware* of the second network existing – it can't tell the second router from a regular host and it doesn't know that 192.168.1.x is behind it. You would normally connect the two networks by adding appropriate routes manually. (With "home gateway" routers, though, connections from the 2nd network outbound will still work, as a home router is designed to masquerade all packets as if they come from its own address – but inbound ones still won't.)

(Frequent advice on this site is to *not* use the second router as an actual router, but only as a bridge – in which case it doesn't create a separate subnet, instead just expands the same network retaining the same addressing.)